# AngularJS directive template not rendering, or working, no error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

Currently, I'm struggling with getting this simple directive to load into the DOM. My results have varied from seeing nothing at all inserted into the directive's custom element/attribute to seeing my app's shell index.html (it's header to be exact) inserted within...

[What the browser painted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q6jo.jpg)

[DOM representation(my index.html inserted instead)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pun3f.png)

I've combed through a lot of question asked on here about the subject, but most tend to refer to Angular's naming normalization or go into more advanced topics.

The directives is:

```
blocJams.directive('bjSellingPoint', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: '/directives/selling-point.html'
  }
});
```

The template for the directive

```
<div class="point column third">
  <span class="ion-music-note"></span>
  <h5 class="point-title"> Choose your music </h5>
  <p class="point-description"> The world is full of music; why should you have to listen to music someone else chose</p>
</div>
```

and I'm referencing the directive inside a view's template like this

```
...        
<section class="selling-points container clearfix">
  <bj-selling-point></bj-selling-point>
</section>
...
```

Additionally, here's the module, route, and controller it's supposed to be in

```
var blocJams = angular.module('blocJams', ['ui.router']);

blocJams.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
   });

   $stateProvider
      .state('landing', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'LandingCtrl',
      templateUrl:  '/templates/landing.html'
   })
});
...

...
blocJams.controller('LandingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.tagline = 'Turn the music up!';
}]);
```

And the file structure

```
app/
-pages/
--index.html
-scripts/
--app.js
-templates/
--landing.html
-directives
--selling-points.html
```

Comment: can you post a snippet or fiddle

Comment: I think its to do with the pathing of the template URL, I tried to replicate your issue on my computer. I did get similar results, try using `"app/templates/landing.html"` and play around with that value. I managed to get it show up.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @TheLazyChap. Trying it out now...

Comment: Will post a fiddle if that's unsuccessful @gaurav5430.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with the pathname for the directive's template. However not in the way that would be immediately obvious.

Since I'm using a starter project with a pre-configured gruntfile, attempting to change my app's file structure to that recommended by Google's Angular Styleguide turned out to have unintended consequences of leaving out my template in its new directory.

Probably obvious if setting up your own grunt tasks, but tricky for newcomers like me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @TheLazyChap

Comment: so the issue was with a grunt script that was running on your project, and had nothing to do with angular?  That would have been pretty impossible for an outside viewer to identify, and doesn't seem particularly helpful to others in the future, since your answer is referring to an entire framework that wasn't mentioned in the question at all.

Comment: Glad you sort it out, keep learning friend. :) I had a lot of struggle when I started, now I personally prefer hand crafting my structure bit by bit. I learn so much and now I have my own structure which I've managed to put into a yeoman scaffold for local use.

Comment: @Claies Yes, that's correct. It was only after hours of investigating that I discovered the issue lay within my grunt script and not Angular itself. I was contemplating taking the question down but thought it might be useful to others newcomers just starting out. 

I'm also new to stack exchange so if it would be advisable to take it down, I wouldn't be against that. Or if there's a way I can rephrase the post title, tags, snippets included, and category so it could be helpful to others, I'd be all ears! Welcoming all advice and feedback.